# Pandas, Horizontal Bar Chart With Error Bars

Tags: python, pandas, plot, bar-chart

In Pandas, how to make the Error Bars inside horizontal Bar Chart to be horizontal as well?

I [tried it and my Error Bars inside horizontal Bar Chart is vertical](https://gist.github.com/suntong/8740c0b6a67cfc79856b).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code:

```
means.plot(yerr=errors, ax=ax, kind='barh')
```

You used `yerr`, so your error bars are aligned with the vertical axis. Change that to `xerr`, and the error bars will be horizontal.